# accessing to an object which current object is a part of

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring

It does seem quite an easy task to solve, but I couldn't find out a way nevertheless.

Say I have two classes

```
class Grid {
   private Square[][] sq;
   public Grid(){
      // don't like this
      seq[0][0] = new Square(this);
      // etc.
   }
   public Collection<Square> getNeighbours( Square sq ){ ... }
   public boolean isFull(){ ... }
}

class Square {
    private Grid grid;
    Set<Worker> set;
    public Square(Grid grid){ 
      this.grid = grid; 
      set.add(new Worker(this));
    }
    public void dealWithNeighbours(){
       for( Square s : grid.getNeighbours()) {....}
    }
    public boolean isGridFull(){
      // now it is officially stupid
      return grid.isFull();
    }
}
```

It is even worse when I add a new layer to this like:

```
 class Worker extends Thread{
     private final Square sq;
     public(Square sq){
       this.sq = sq;
     }
     private boolean anyMoreFreeSpace(){
       !sq.isGridFull();
     }
     @Override
     public void run(){
       if( anyMoreFreeSpace () ) { ... }
       ...
     }

 }
```

Now the problem is that every time I need to initiate a new Square object , I also must give a reference to its calling object. Because square does not possess any information about its surroundings. It gets even worse when I need some information about the main top owner. Then I must link layers to each other like in case of `isGridFull()`.

In real code I have 3-levels of such dependencies and it is already got very messy. I would like to know a good way to deal with this situation. What would be the correct design of this ?

Comment: Passing `this` is the correct way of dealing with it.  Although in general, if things need to access their owner's owner's owner, the design probably needs rethinking.

Comment: @ayan ahmedov, is my answer helpful for you? If not, provide more details or make a comment about why it isn't, please. I still can try to help you solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Robin, why you don't just tell the squares about their neighbours?

If you have reasons don't tell them, so I hope that the next may be helpful for you )

When you want dependencies get weaker, you need to introduce new abstraction level which has all information about `Grid`, `Square`, `Worker`. The previous three classes can know anything about one another. As I understand, you already have such abstraction level: some "main top owner".

So make `Owner` be aware about all, and make `Grid` `Square` and `Worker` dump.

```
public class Owner {
  //structure that store grid, all related squares and all related workers
  private Grid grid;
  private Map<Square, Collection<Worker>> squareWorkerMap;      

  public Grid getGrid() {
    return grid;
  }

  public Collection<Square> getAllSquares() {
    return squareWorkerMap.values();
  } 

  public Collection<Worker> getWorkers(Square sq) {
    squareWorkerMap.get(sq);
  } 

  public ??? getSquare(Worker worker) {
    //implementation depends on if worker can belong to many squares
  }
}

public class Grid {
  private Owner mainTopOwner;

  public Collection<Square> getSquares() {
    return mainTopOwner.getAllSquares();
  }
  public Collection<Worker> getWorkers(Square sq) {
    return mainTopOwner.getWorkers(sq);
  }
}

public class Square {
  private Owner mainTopOwner;

  public Collection<Workers> getWorkers() {
    return mainTopOwner.getWorkers(this);  
  }
  public Grid getGrid() {
     return mainTopOwner.getGrid;
  } 
}

public class Worker {
  private Owner mainTopOwner;

  public Square getSquare() {
    return mainTopOwner.getSquare(this)
  }
  public Grid getGrid() {
    return mainTopOwner.getGrid;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in a generic way: Not it's not a good idea. If code starts to feel messy, rethink you design!

I am not 100% sure, what you trying to achieve, but as @Oli Charlesworth statet, `this` is bascially the right way.

Re wright your question, probably you will get a better answer then.

**Edit:**
Just as a quick edit, why don't you tell the squares about their neighbors, could ease things a bit?